# How to reconfigure R with Xorg-X11 on Centos?

Tags: r, centos6

I have installed R but I was facing errors for storing plots as jpeg or png.
I ran:

capabilities():

```
 jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua    http/ftp  sockets   
 FALSE     FALSE   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE    FALSE   TRUE     TRUE    
 libxml   fifo   cledit    iconv     NLS     profmem    cairo 
 TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     FALSE
```

I have also installed

```
xorg-x11-server-Xorg

JPEG Installed Packages
libjpeg-turbo.x86_64                 1.2.90-5.el7                  @anaconda/7.3
openjpeg-libs.x86_64                 1.5.1-10.el7                  @dvd

Installed Packages
libpng.x86_64                      2:1.5.13-7.el7_2                @anaconda/7.3
libpng-devel.x86_64                2:1.5.13-7.el7_2                @dvd

Installed Packages
libX11.x86_64                       1.6.3-3.el7                    @anaconda/7.3
libX11-common.noarch                1.6.3-3.el7                    @anaconda/7.3
libX11-devel.x86_64                 1.6.3-3.el7                    @dvd
libXau-devel.x86_64                 1.0.8-2.1.el7                  @dvd
libXdmcp.x86_64                     1.1.1-6.1.el7                  @dvd
libXfont.x86_64                     1.5.1-2.el7                    @dvd
libXt.x86_64                        1.1.4-6.1.el7                  @dvd
libXt-devel.x86_64                  1.1.4-6.1.el7                  @dvd
libxcb-devel.x86_64                 1.11-4.el7                     @dvd
libxkbfile.x86_64                   1.0.8-5.el7                    @dvd

Installed Packages
abrt-addon-xorg.x86_64                            2.1.11-45.el7                     @anaconda/7.3
xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64                        1:7.5-20.el7                      @dvd
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch                       7.5-9.el7                         @dvd
xorg-x11-proto-devel.noarch                       7.7-13.el7                        @dvd
xorg-x11-server-Xorg.x86_64                       1.17.2-22.el7                     @dvd
xorg-x11-server-common.x86_64                     1.17.2-22.el7                     @dvd
xorg-x11-xkb-utils.x86_64                         7.7-12.el7                        @dvd
```

Still I don't know how to re compile R with Xorg-X11 to get the plots stored in as PNG/JPEG

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  : 
  unable to start device PNG
Calls: png
In addition: Warning message:
In png("abc") : unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Execution halted
```